# Set slider drawer height

Tags: android

I have a slider drawer in my application. If I set wrap_content as a value for the layout_height field, the slider drawer will stretch on the whole screen. Using a constant as a height is not a good alternative either.
Is it possible to have a slider drawer with the height of it's content?

```
  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/frameLayout" 
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:background="@color/blue"/>
    <SlidingDrawer 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:handle="@+id/handle" 
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:id="@+id/slide" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_header"> 
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ingredients_list_title"/>
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up"
         />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_row_background">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_ant_title"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_above="@+id/gallery"
             android:orientation="vertical">
              <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@drawable/divider"
                android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
                android:fadingEdge="none"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Gallery 
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/list_row_background"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the container? A LinearLayout? Add another empty element, and give them both a weight of 1.

Comment: It was a FrameLayout. I've changed it to LinearLayout and set the weights. But is the same thing.

Comment: I've posted it in the initial question. I did some fixing and the last conclusion is that if i set the weights to 1 for the dummy view and the drawer, both of them will have the height equal to 1/2 of the screen. I would like to have a sliding drawer with the height equal to it's content height.

Answer (score 1):

Use `topOffset` attribute for **SlidingDrawer**.

like this.

```
<SlidingDrawer 
    ...
    android:topOffset="800px">
```